# Difference between SQL Database and SQL Server in Microsoft Azure Portal

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I see 2 Azure offering SQL Database and SQL Server on Azure Portal, whats the difference ? I understand SQL Database is SaaS and SQL Server is PaaS.

[image]

Comment: The SQL Server is the logical container for one or more SQL Databases

Answer (score 8):

The SQL server (lower case s for server) here is a strong container for 1 or more databases which can be of multiple types. Today you can have Azure SQL Database, SQL Data Warehouse and SQL Stretch database all in the same logical SQL server. The server is the public endpoint you connect to. Other objects like logins are ***hosted*** there also.

SQL Server (upper case S for Server) is the "box" product that can be hosted on your own machines or in Azure VMs as an IaaS solution. You can in most cases think of an Azure SQL server **conceptually** as very similar to the box SQL Server instance but actual underlying setup is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be on Windows server and T-SQL language differences. That's most of it. See the Microsoft docs for further information.

https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/09/azure-whats-the-difference-between-sql-database-and-sql-server/